# WPF - How to add event handler to element from outside the class?

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app

I am searching for answer many hours and with no success. There is the way to do that, but every included element has to be static. What is not suitable for me.

I have MainPage class and Tile class. This tile class instantiates few kinds of tiles in MainPage layout. I need to add to some kinds of these tiles Tapped event. This event should modify MainPage elements.

What is the best way to do that? I always end with "non-static warning", as you can see in the code:

```
public class Tile
{
   public static Grid buttonTile_MapPanel(int rowNum, int colNum)
    {
        Grid mapPanelButton = new Grid();
        mapPanelButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 50, 50, 50));
        TextBlock title = new TextBlock();
        title.Text = "Mapa";
        title.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        title.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        mapPanelButton.Children.Add(title);

        //this will be signed as error: An object reference is required for non static field...
        mapPanelButton.Tapped += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage.mapPanelService);

        return mapPanelButton;
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public void mapPanelService(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        MapPanel.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
    }  
}
```

Comment: You have to make `MainPage.mapPanelService` static.

Comment: @Sinatr - But in this case, i have to set static `MainPage.MapPanel` too. This panel is declared in xaml, so I am not sure how to do that. I didn't find anything about declaring modificators in xaml. Is there way how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem was bad type of handler, which demanded something else than it should.

Correct code:
    public void dataPanelService(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
   .
   .
   .